# При выходе с спящего режима компьютер не корректно работает

Tags: windows-10

Возникла проблема, что при выходи со спящего режима, компьютер не стабильно начинает работать (частично). Складывается ощущение потеря частично данных в оперативной памяти.

Проявляется это таким образом:

1. Появляется 60% вероятность появление "экрана смерти". Код ошибки разный
2. Программы "крашаться" или не частично перестают работать. Например, в браузере может не открывать вкладку или перестать работать какой-то компонент.

Дополнительные данные:
К сожалению в данный момент не могу сказать точные данные, но знаю:

В качестве накопителя стоит - SSD;
Процессор AMD  (точные данные скажу позже, если нужно);
ОС-Windows 10 Home (лицензия);
Оперативной памяти 4+4;

В биосе отключен режим экономии энергии. До выхода в спящий режим нареканий нет. Спасибо

Comment: может это не сон а гибернация?

Comment: @Andrew, написано на русском "сон". Гибернации нет в списке. Скорее не включена

Comment: Вероятно, сможет помочь переустановка видеодрайвера с оф.сайта.

Comment: @vp_arth, первое что сделал. Но не помогло ;-)